# How to calculate mean and standard deviation based on percentage

Tags: r, tidyverse, mean

Here is my data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = " Group L1 L2 L3 L4 l5
Q 0% 10% 0% 70% 20%
K 20% 20% 20% 10% 30%", header = TRUE)
```

I want to calculate L1 times 1, L2 times 2, L3 times 3, L4 times 4 and L5 times 5 for Q and k.

I want to get the following table:

```
Group  L1  L2  L3  L4  l5 Mean   SD
    Q  0% 10%  0% 70% 20%  0.8 1.19
    K 20% 20% 20% 10% 30% 0.62 0.51
```

Note: I have 100 rows and this is part of my sample to show the purpose of my question. Much appreciated for your help.

Comment: How is the mean of the vector `0% 10% 0% 70% 20%` equal to 0.8? On a related note: Calculating the mean of percentages (proportions) can be dangerous (the mean of a ratio is not the same as the ratio of the means!). Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Instead of repeatedly stating "It does not reflect my table/output" to the answers posted here, please *explain* how those numbers are derived (which you've now changed by the way). How is the mean of `0% 10% 0% 70% 20%` 0.8? How is the mean in the second line 0.62?

Comment: @MauritsEvers; take the mean and sd of 1:5*x/100, where x is the values in each row

Comment: @user20650 *"Sorry, I feel your question is not relevant as you can easily see the output of intrest. Just devote , I understand"* I, unfortunately, don't understand a word you're saying.

Comment: not tidyverse but... `library(data.table); setDT(df1) ; melt(df1, id.vars = "Group")[, value := as.numeric(gsub("%", "", value))][ , .(mean=mean(1:5*value/100), sd=sd(1:5*value/100)), by=Group]`

Comment: ... but to get full outcome you can `cbind` or merge `df1[m, on="Group"]`, where `m` is the previous results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(L1:L5) %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(sub("%", "", value))/100 * 1:5) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(value), SD = sd(value)) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)

#   Group  L1  L2  L3  L4  L5 id Mean        SD
# 1     Q  0% 10%  0% 70% 20%  1 0.80 1.1916375
# 2     K 20% 20% 20% 10% 30%  2 0.62 0.5118594
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Group = structure(2:1, .Label = c("K", "Q"), class = "factor"), 
  L1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("0%", "20%"), class = "factor"), 
  L2 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("10%", "20%"), class = "factor"), 
  L3 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("0%", "20%"), class = "factor"), 
  L4 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("10%", "70%"), class = "factor"), 
  L5 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("20%", "30%"), class = "factor")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: @use2020 just revise `pivot_longer(L1:L5)` to `pivot_longer(L1:l5)`.

Comment: @use2020 `L1:l5` mean `L1 L2 L3 L4 l5` in syntax of `pivot_longer`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your help; @Darren Tsai

Answer (score 2):

We could first remove the `"%"` sign from the columns. Multiply `df1` by `1:5` and calculate rowwise mean and sd.

```
df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) as.numeric(sub('%', '', x)))
temp <- as.matrix(sweep(df1[-1], 2, seq_along(df1[-1]), `*`))
df1$Mean <- rowMeans(temp)/100
df1$Sds <- matrixStats::rowSds(temp)/100
#Or to keep it in base R
#df1$Sds <- apply(temp, 1, sd)/100
df1

#  Group L1 L2 L3 L4 l5 Mean     Sds
#1     Q  0 10  0 70 20 0.80 1.19164
#2     K 20 20 20 10 30 0.62 0.51186
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Group = structure(2:1, .Label = c("K", "Q"),class = "factor"),
L1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("0%", "20%"), class = "factor"), 
L2 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("10%", "20%"), class = "factor"), 
L3 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("0%", "20%"), class = "factor"), 
L4 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("10%", "70%"), class = "factor"), 
l5 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("20%", "30%"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: @use2020 It reflected your original input. If you run this on your updated data, it still gives you the expected output.

Comment: @use2020 I have updated the answer based on your new data. Let me know what do you mean by "wrong" ? As I said earlier it works for me for the data you have shared and expected output you have shown.